# Hadoop Mapreduce with two jars (one of the jars is needed on namenode only)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The mapred task is a very simple 'wordcount' implemented by Java (plz, see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount ).

after the last line, "job.waitForCompletion(true);"
I add some code implemented by Jython.

It means the libraries for Jythoon is only needed on namenode.
However, I added all libraries for Jython to a single jar, and then
executed it

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar in out
```

The wordcount is done without any problem.

The problem I want to solve is I have to heavy libraries for Jython that is not needed for the slave nodes(mappers and reducers). the jar is almost 15M (upper than 14M is for Jython).

Can I split them, and get the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody knows this question.

I've solved this problem as follows: even if it's not the best.

Simply, copy jython.jar to /usr/local/hadoop (or path of hadoop installed) which is the default classpath of hadoop, and make a jar without jython.jar

If you need very big libraries to mapreduce task, then

1. upload jython.jar to hdfs

   hadoop fs -put jython.jar Lib/jython.jar
2. add the follow line to your main code

   DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new URI("Lib/jython.jar"));